# How to Add Value corresponding to the field (The field in each list will be different) in any one list with SharePoint C# ConsoleApp

Tags: c#, sharepoint, console-application

How can I loop get field to replace listItem["Title"] = listItem[field in list] and read the corresponding fields in the list while the lists have different fields and the field type of the field is different

```
string listNameAnything = console.ReadLine(); 

string inputValueAnything = console.ReadLine();

List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listNameAnything);  

ListItemCreationInformation newItem = new ListItemCreationInformation();  
ListItem listItem = list.AddItem(newItem);  
listItem["Title"] = inputValueAnything;  

//WHat I need to handle it 
  
listItem.Update();  
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use the below script to get all field names:

```
        ContentTypeCollection contentTypes = list.ContentTypes;
        ctx.Load(contentTypes);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        ContentType contentType = contentTypes[0];                         
        FieldCollection fields = contentType.Fields;
        ctx.Load(fields);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        foreach(Field field in fields)
        {
             Console.WriteLine("field type:"+field.TypeAsString + ";  field name :"+ field.Title);

        }
```